Angular async pipe with @for
I am using latest angular version 18.1.0 and want to use async pipe for an array of countries fetched from the backend using http client. But while using new angular feature of @for it give me error:

Type 'Country' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns
an iterator.

My code is as follows
country.component.html
<main>
    <select name="countries" id="countries-selection">
        @for (country of countries$ | async; track $index) {
        <option value="{{country}}">{{ country }}</option>
        }
    </select>
</main>

country.component.ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Country } from './country.model';
import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-country',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './country.component.html',
  styleUrl: './country.component.css'
})
export class CountryComponent {

  countries$: Observable<Country>;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
      this.countries$ = this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/countries').pipe(
      map((response: any) => <Country> response.json()));

  }

}

EDIT:
I am getting following array from the server:
[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Australia",
      "isCurrent": true,
      "timezone": "Asia/Karachi"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Canada",
      "isCurrent": true,
      "timezone": "Asia/Karachi"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Finland",
      "isCurrent": false,
      "timezone": "Europe/Tallinn"
    }

]

What could be the possible solution if I want to use rxjs and not JS async/await for fetching the countries?

please share the API response

I'd venture to say that response.json() isn't doing what you think it's doing. Moreover, the response.json() isn't required in Angular since long time now. Try: this.countries$ = this.httpClient.get<Country[]>('http://localhost:3000/countries'); without the pipe(map())

@for iterates over arrays. According to your types, countries$ is an Observable of a Country object, which Angular doesn't accept to iterate over. Just add [] to indicate that it's a list of Country objects:
export class CountryComponent {

  countries$: Observable<Country[]>;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
      this.countries$ = this.httpClient.get<Country[]>('http://localhost:3000/countries');
  }
}

One additional note, calling response.json() is not something which Angular's HTTP client supports. It will parse to JSON by default, so probably you can just skip this part.

I  have edited my question with the server response I am getting. Actually I am getting an array from the server.

But your type is still Observable<Country> when it needs to be an array e.g. Observable<Country[]>

@Fahad this is what I suspected, as I said in my answer, you need to adjust the types. They currently do not reflect reality.

@Fahad stackblitz reference

Thanks a lot @JSON Derulo, Naren and others. you have saved me hours. There was some silly mistakes in my code. Now everything works.
